# Angular component style budget

Tags: css, angular

Why is it bad to put a lot of css in individual component's css in Angular? When I exceed the budget defined in package.json (which is 2 MB) by default, I get a warning.

I have the following scenario. I'm making a casnio webapp which consists of user dashboard and roulette wheel. The roulette wheel has a totally different css from the dashboard, so I was thinking about putting it into separate components. But, I'm trying to figure out, why does putting a lot of css in the separate component isn't recommended, as it apparently slows down the app, while putting that same css into the main styles.css doesn't slow it down as much

Answer (score 0):

Its because css that defined in your component-css is bundled into the javascript source-code while styles.css instead is an independent file.

A suitable solution for your problem: Create a css-file for your roulette-styles and import this in your styles.css